# Rails: will_paginate Undefined method `paginate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, will-paginate

I'm trying to use will_paginate but it didn't work for me maybe  I'm doing things wrong 
this is my users controller

```
  def index
    @users = (current_user.blank? ? User.all : User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id])).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
```

but I get this error `undefined method`paginate'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you certain that you've included "will_paginate" in your Gemfile, run `bundle install` and restarted your server?  If not, can you include the whole stacktrace?

Also, if you want to, you can restructure to Rails 4 style scoping like this:

```
def index
  @users = user_scope.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end 

private

def user_scope
  current_user ? User.where.not(id: current_user.id) : User.all
end
```

Comment: I had an exact same issue as described in the problem and server restart fixed it for me.